# Checking an array' elements to see if n-1 value is in a database as reference

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a database with an ID field and a reference field which references to another tuple with the id.

```
table  
id | ref   
1  | null
2  | null
3  | 1
4  | 1
5  | 1
6  | 4
7  | 6
```

I want to validate a given array to see if each element has the n-1 elements value as a reference. If the chain is somewhere broken.... the array doesn't validate.

For instance: `array(1,4,6,7)` validates while the `ref(7) = 6`, `ref(6)=4` and the `ref(4)=1`

Comment: Have you tried something that we can see?

Comment: you also need to check for looping references otherwise you create an endless loop :) - But I can tell you the answer: It works by programming it. What did you try so far? Into which problem did you run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$source = [1 => null, 2 => null, 3 => 1, 4 => 1, 5 => 1, 6 => 4, 7 => 6];

$a = [1, 4, 6, 7];
$b = [1, 2, 3];

function validate($source, $check) {
    $thisNum = array_shift($check);
    //This checks the first number, which must not have a ref, it will have NULL value in source array.
    if ($source[$thisNum] != NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    do {
        $nextNum = array_shift($check);
        //This checks that the next number in the list has the ref of the previous number in the source array
        if ($source[$nextNum] !== $thisNum) {
            return false;
        }
        //This is so the next check can use the current next num as the current num to check
        $thisNum = $nextNum;
    } while (count($check));
    //If we haven't failed yet, it must be good!
    return true;
}

var_dump(validate($source, $a));
var_dump(validate($source, $b));
```

Result was:

```
boolean true
boolean false
```

TBH: I hardly ever use do-while instead of while, but I believe it is needed here so you can always run the first check. This function does NOT validate that your array has at least 2 entries which is a requirement for the function, so add that check in.